# DB2 xquery to html

Tags: html, xml, db2, xquery

I am trying to write an xquery for DB2 to give me an HTML output. I have something like:

```
xquery 
<html>
<head>
<title>Circuit Idea Catalog</title>
</head>
<body>
<table border="1">
<tr>
<th>Design ID</th>
<th>Title</th>
<th>Abstract</th>
</tr>
{
for $x in db2-fn:xmlcolumn('IDEA.DETAILS')/Ideas/Record_Info
order by $x/DesignID
return <tr><td>{data($x/DesignID)}</td><td>{data($x/Title)}</td><td>{data($x/parent::*/Design_Details/Abstract)}</td></tr>
}
</table>
</body>
</html>~
```

This does not work properly and does not give me the full results compared to if I just have this:

```
xquery 
for $x in db2-fn:xmlcolumn('IDEA.DETAILS')/Ideas/Record_Info
order by $x/DesignID
return <tr><td>{data($x/DesignID)}</td><td>{data($x/Title)}</td><td>{data($x/parent::*/Design_Details/Abstract)}</td></tr>
```

Somehow it does not like the tags. Also it gives a lot of extra text which I don't want in my html file. Is there a way just get the html output and save it to a file.

It seems that the output is being truncated. How can I run a query and get the full output to a file?

Comment: What output do you get, what would be the expected output? Your XQuery code looks identical to me, right? I don't see why DB2 should evaluate this any different...

Comment: http://amolnpujari.wordpress.com/2008/04/12/db2-native-xml/ and http://amolnpujari.wordpress.com/2008/04/07/sqlxml-vs-xquery/ ,oght help you